# Conditionals doesn't work with if, how to convert values to integer? in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

The problem i had is that the if conditionals doesnt work, i guess it's related to the type of value.

At the moment i didn't know how to solve it, but make a test with:

```bsh
var=T
if [ -n "$var" ] && [ "$var" -eq "$var" ] 2>/dev/null; then
    echo number
else
    echo not a number
fi
```

And show me that my "number" its not a number.

Bellow is the script doing it with the problem where always enter to the first if even being the condition wrong.

```
SENT="/home/trader/monitor2/ArchivosPruebas/CambiosLiquidacion5deUWT/Enviados.log";
RECEIVED="/home/trader/monitor2/ArchivosPruebas/CambiosLiquidacion5deUWT/Recibidos.log";   
RESULT="/home/trader/CCVPending/Liquidaciones/Liquidaciones.log"

T0=$(cat $SENT | grep 63=1 | wc -l);T1=$(cat $SENT | grep 63=2 | wc -l);T2=$(cat $SENT | grep 63=3 | wc -l);T3=$(cat $SENT | grep 63=4 | wc -l);
T4=$(cat $SENT | grep 63=5 | wc -l);T5=$(cat $SENT | grep 63=9 | wc -l);TOTAL=$(($T0+$T1+$T2+$T3+$T4+$T5));

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do
echo "------ T+$i -----" >> $RESULT
ii=$((1+$i)); if [ $i = 5 ]; then ii=9; fi; 
T=$(($((T$i)))); echo T $T con i en 63=$ii

if [ $T -le 10 ] || [ $T -gt 0 ] ; then
        echo if; cat $SENT | grep 63=$ii | grep 487=0 | sed "s/.*31=/Qty=/"|sed "s/.32=/,Price=/"|sed "s/.48=.*.55=/,Emisora=/"|sed "s/.60=.*.63=$ii/,T+0/"|sed "s/.487=.*.54=/,Side=/"|sed "s/.453=.*.448=/,Firm=/"   | sed "s/.447=.*//" | grep -x "Qty=.*.,Price=.*.,Firm=[A-Z][A-Z]*.">> $RESULT
elif [ $T -le 30 ] || [ $T -gt 10 ] ; then echo elif
        echo elif; cat $SENT | grep 63=$ii | grep 487=0 | sed "s/.*48=.*.55=/Emisora=/"|sed "s/.60=.*.448=/,Firm=/"| sed "s/.447=.*//" | grep -E "Emisora=[A-Z].*.,Firm=[A-Z][A-Z].*." >> $RESULT
else echo else;
echo $T >> $RESULT
fi
done
```

Comment: It’s really not clear what your question is. Where is your code failing to do what you want? What do you expect to to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: `T=$(($((T$i))))` - what?

Comment: test for -n is not "numeric" test, it is "non-zero-length" test.

Comment: The test `[ $T -le 10 ] || [ $T -gt 0 ]` will be true for any number. Perhaps you meant to use `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: @guest No. (a) it would be true for any digit {1..9}. (b) It throws [: j: integer expression expected where T=j.

Comment: @guest Sorry: OP did mean &&. However, just as well it didn't get here past the numeric test, because that really does crash the script.

Comment: `cat $SENT | grep 63=5 | wc -l` or just `grep -c 63=5 $SENT`

Comment: @guest It needs a complete rewrite, for sure. I would give it a shot, but I can't figure what it even aims to do, and it shows no inputs or results. Deep down, it is probably 10 lines of awk. Also reads SENT eight times, and RECEIVED not at all, which suggests a major problem. As does the aversion to using newlines.

Comment: @guest as you said the use of && instead of || solve my issue. 

I dig in that and found this guide http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html#AEN4294

Comment: Also your comments let me think more about my Script and rewrite it will be an option with certain details as @rexkogitans mention or even implementing with awk instead of  sed. Im new working with these kind of scripts and its a little bit tricky bash scripts for me.

Comment: My inputs are logs from a FIX protocol wich has some tags value to identify a business application and i am analizing it in order to make more easier my work. 

In that script i didnt show the analize of the RECEIVED logs because at the moment i dont know the different cases deppending the business application.

Comment: Here an example of my output, with the conditionals i filter the information in different way to be shown:

Enviado  T+0=5, T+1=1, T+2=22300, T+3=0, T+4=0, T+5=0, TOTAL=22306  

inicio T+1=1
Qty=24.600,Price=11305,Emisora=VMEX 19,T+0,Side=2,Firm=VFMXMXM1  
fin T+1=1  

Qty=4.910,Price=4169,Emisora=UWT *,T+0,Side=2,Firm=CBOIMXM1  
Qty=4.900,Price=11803,Emisora=UWT *,T+0,Side=2,Firm=CBOIMXM1  
Qty=4.900,Price=622,Emisora=UWT *,T+0,Side=2,Firm=CBOIMXM1  
Qty=5.120,Price=1,Emisora=UWT *,T+0,Side=2,Firm=CBOIMXM1  
Qty=4.910,Price=1,Emisora=UWT *,T+0,Side=2,Firm=GBMSMXM1  
fin T+0=5

Answer (score 0):

Your test [ -n $T ] is testing for non-zero length, not numeric.

```
Paul--) T=7x7
Paul--) case "$T" in (+([[:digit:]])) echo "Y";; (*) echo "N";; esac
N
Paul--) T=787
Paul--) case "$T" in (+([[:digit:]])) echo "Y";; (*) echo "N";; esac
Y
```

There is a simpler test, but it requires setting a global shell option which may affect other parts of your script.

```
Paul--) shopt -s extglob
Paul--) T=787
Paul--) [[ "$T" = +([0-9]) ]] && echo "Y" || echo "N"
Y
Paul--) T=7x7
Paul--) [[ "$T" = +([0-9]) ]] && echo "Y" || echo "N"
N
```